# automatically renewing records when the last day of year

Tags: sql, document, records, auto-renewing

I'm developing a c# application that consists of Document Incoming System for my police station.

In this system, variable document's contents are been saved to an SQL database. I must give them a "Document Number".

I'm achieving all of these, but i want that every years last day such as `31.12.2014`, the numbers that have been given to a document like "2145" will turn to "1" at the the first day of year `01.01.2015`.

So, the records must be `2014/2145`. and the last days of years turns to `2015/1`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need a bit more information for this to be clear.  If I understand, you just want to update all the document numbers at the end of the year to reflect the new format?  Do you want to save the old number?

Comment: Actually, you want to do this on the first day of the new year, not the last day of the old one.

Comment: If your database engine, which you did not specify, has sequences, use one for your document numbers.  Then set up a scheduled job to re-set the sequence at 00:00 every January 1st.

Comment: of course im saving the old numbers. im thinking to add new column and substring the dates 'Year' part. such as substring the last four number of 11.07.2014 and then in the new columns writing 2014/1478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You count the existing documents for the same year, then add one.

So if you want to store a document that belongs to 2013, you first count how many existing documents you have in 2013, then add one.

I can't write the sql for you, because you haven't described the data structure, but it should be simple enough using SQL [`COUNT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx), and [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to retrieve only the year from a date field.